# EF Core DbContext Testing with Sqlite and using SQL Server in production

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sqlite, ef-core-2.0

I am using Sqlite with EF Core for testing my `DbContext`, however I have configured the model using schemas and datatypes that are SQL Server specific. I am using SQL Server in production. So far my tests work without modifying the model. Why is this working, are model changes being ignored rather than failing? An example is that for every table I define a schema, which is not supported in Sqlite.

Comment: I highly recommend you match the db platform you will be deploying to in production locally for development. You are setting yourself up for failure if you don't do this.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Even though the language is similar, the sematic differences are enough to cause major issues in the transition, not to mention the additional maintenance load. Strongly urge anyone doing this to set up your development environment as close to production as possible (without using live data) as soon as possible.